# Trying to turn all white areas in a grayscaled imaged to black

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

As the title says I'm trying to turn all the white parts in my grayscaled photo to black. I tried using this code right here

```
img_file = os.path.join(img_dir, os.listdir(img_dir)[1])
img = Image.open(img_file).convert('L')

npImage = np.array(img)

LUT = np.zeros(256, dtype=np.uint8)
LUT[255] = 0

img = Image.fromarray(LUT[npImage])
img.show()
```

but my output is a purely black image.

Comment: `LUT = npImage.copy(); LUT[LUT ==255] = 0`

Answer (score 1):

LUT is an array of all 0s and 0's will display as black.  What you want to do is create a for loop to access all of the values in npImage, and if necessary change to black.

`LUT = np.zeros(256, dtype=np.uint8)` creates an array of 0's of length 256

`LUT[255] = 0` sets the 256th element in LUT to 0

Comment: ohhhhhh, i totally misunderstood what that does. Thank you!